# Instantiate prefab base on the value of multidimensional array (C# UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello guys I just wanted to ask if it is possible to instantiate prefab base on the value of your `Multidimensional Array` for example I have this data.

> 10 20 11
>
> 00 21 10
>
> 00 00 00
>
> 00 00 00
>
> 00 00 00
>
> 00 00 00

Now here is my code

```
string road1 = "";
    for (int y = 0; y < bsb.ArrBigRoad.GetLength(0); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < bsb.ArrBigRoad.GetLength(1); x++)
        {
            road1 += string.Format("{0:D2}", bsb.ArrBigRoad[y, x] / 100);
            road1 += ".";
        }
        road1 += "\n";
    }
Debug.Log(road1);
```

Right now I am printing it using `Label` like this

```
[SerializeField] public UILabel info_scores_bigroad;

info_scores_bigroad.text = road1;
```

Comment: so your question is "can I instantiate a prefab by it's name"? or i'm missing something? Cause you are building an string with your multidimensional array, and I understand that you want to do: Instantiate(road1), isn't it?

Comment: @Lotan yes that's what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Lotan what I did was something like this

**SetScore.cs**

```
public void Set( int score )
{
    int who = score / 1000;

    if (who == 1)
    {
        NGUITools.SetActive(obj_player, true );
        NGUITools.SetActive(obj_banker, false);
    }
    else if( who == 2)
    {
        NGUITools.SetActive(obj_player, false);
        NGUITools.SetActive(obj_banker, true);
    }
    else
    {
        NGUITools.SetActive(obj_player, false);
        NGUITools.SetActive(obj_banker, false);

        NGUITools.SetActive(lbl_tie_no.gameObject, false);
        NGUITools.SetActive(spr_playerPair.gameObject, false);
        NGUITools.SetActive(spr_bankerPair.gameObject, false);
        return;
    }
}
```

Then pattern what I have on my 2d Array like this

**Game.cs**

```
public IEnumerator ShowScoreBoard_BigRoad(int[,]  arrBigRoad)
{
    NGUITools.DestroyChildren(pos_bigroad);

    for (int y = 0; y < arrBigRoad.GetLength(0); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < arrBigRoad.GetLength(1); x++)
        {
            int score = arrBigRoad[y, x];

            GameObject o = Instantiate(prefab_bigroad) as GameObject;
            o.transform.SetParent(pos_bigroad);
            o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

            o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x * SX_, y* SY_, 0);
            NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);

            // 1011, 2000, 3000, 

            bsbBigRoad s = o.GetComponent<bsbBigRoad>();
            s.Set(score);
        }
    }

    yield break;
}
```

But thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you 2 different ways:

1.Create a Switch/Enum, with the possible prefabs you can instantiate, something like:

```
//Possible Prefabs, link them on editor
public GameObject car;
public GameObject road;
public GameObject truck;

//Used to instantiate the new object
public GameObject newObject;

switch(road1){
    case 'car':
        newObject = Instantiate(car);
        break;
    case 'road':
        newObject = Instantiate(road);
        break;
    case 'truck':
        newObject = Instantiate(truck);
        break;
    default:
        print("error: prefab not exists");
        break;
}
```

2.Using Resources Folder

```
//Used to instantiate the new object
public GameObject newObject;

newObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(road1));
```

Remember that for the case 2 you NEED to create a folder named Resources, and locate the prefabs on that folder.

Comment: @Ginxxx if it works, mark the answer, so others can saw it solved. If not, tell me what you got :)

Comment: Yup i will :) don't worry.